# Criterion for a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be a cyclyc group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Suppose that I have $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z_p}$. Let $|A|=a\cdot b $ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and let me attache a multiplication modulus $p$.
Are the two following requirements

1. There is a cyclic group of order $a$ in $A$
2. There is a cyclic group of order $b$ in $A$

sufficient to insure that $A$ is cyclic under multiplication modulus $p$, that is, there exist an element $g\in A$ with order $a\cdot b$.

Comment: Your title says "cyclic subgroups of a cyclic group", but $\Bbb Z_p$ with the multiplication operation isn't even a group.

Comment: Did you mean addition?

Comment: @Arthur: You're absolutely right! I will edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you exclude $0$ (which would ruin any hope of multiplication being a group operation), there is a counterexample for $p=13$. In that case, the multiplicative group of invertible elements has $12$ elements. Take $A=\{1,12,3, 9,2,5\}$, which has size $6=2\cdot3$, and contains the order $2$ group $\{1,12\}$ and the order $3$ group $\{1,3,9\}$. But it's not a group, since $2\in A$ but $2\cdot 2=4\notin A$.

Comment: Very helpful counterexample, thank you.
In which circumstances then the two requirements of mine, insures that $A$ is a group? [Is that question is right to ask?]

Comment: A little comment @Arthur, I think the wording "would ruin" is more clear that the actual. I must read some times to understand this phrase. By now it seems you are saying that $\Bbb Z_p\setminus\{[p]\}$ is not a multiplicative group.

Comment: @SalechAlhasov The easiest is "when $ab=p-1$", for any other $a,b,p$ you can find counterexamples like mine ($13$ is the first counterexample simply because it's the first prime that allows $ab\neq p-1$, with both $a$ and $b$ greater than $1$). If there are additional criteria in the other cases that guarantee that $A$ is a group (apart from criteria that essentially say "$A$ is a group"), I don't know.

Comment: @Masacroso I agree, and fixed.

Comment: Another thought: let $A_a$ be a cyclic group of order $a$, and $A_b$ a cyclic group of order $b$, s.t $\gcd(x,y)=1$ for every $x\in A_a$ and $y\in A_b$, interesting if with this criteria we can do something...

Comment: @SalechAlhasov That's difficult for a whole different reason: the $\gcd$ isn't particularly well-defined for congruence classes. For instance, take $2$ and $3$ in $\Bbb Z_{13}$. "Clearly", we have $\gcd(2, 3) = 1$, but note that $2$ and $15$ are _exactly the same thing_ in $\Bbb Z_{13}$, and $\gcd(15, 3) = 3$.